# Change the icon in a (appcelerator titanium) desktop app

Tags: appcelerator

If I change the default default_app_logo.png with mine, i get: Packaging failed with message: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'rfind'

I am doing a desktop app. What I can do?

I tried all of kinds of PNG formats...

I am doing the package on windows platform.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this exact same problem, which only occurs when trying to package the mac version. I was using a custom icon also.

Like you I replaced the default_app_logo.png with mine, and there lies the problem. For some reason, Titanium does not like the PNG format I gave this image.

So what I did is open the default_app_logo.png in GIMP, open my icon in GIMP, copy my icon to the default logo image in a new layer, hide the original image layer (the background) and hit save.

And after this manipulation, packaging for Mac works perfectly. I have no idea in whoch way the two differ, because they have exactly the same size, but the fact is that one gives the error and the other doesn't...